# How to set up a Half-Normal Prior in NIMBLE?

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, nimble

**Can you give me example to write half-normal prior using Nimble package in R?**

For example, if I want my precision variable "tau.b" to follow a Half-Normal(0, 2.5), will it be correct if I put it as below?

`for (k in 1:nvar) {b[k] ~ dnorm(mu.b[k],tau.b[k])}`

`#HALF NORMAL prior for the precision of b[]`

`tau.b ~ dnorm(0, 2.5)`

`tau.b ~ dconstraint(tau.b>0)`

Thanks in advance!

PS: I have tried to read the [Nimble manual](https://r-nimble.org/manuals/NimbleUserManual.pdf) page 53, but it is still not clear to me of how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method (setting `tau.b ~ dnorm(...)` and then using `constraint_data ~ dconstraint(tau.b > 0)` *should* work (the manual specifies that you should set `constraint_data` to 1 in the data provided to the model), but might be overkill/less efficient than specifying a truncated distribution, as

```
tau.b[k] ~ T(dnorm(0, sd = 2.5), 0, )
```

Leaving the last argument blank declares that there is only lower truncation at 0, with no truncation at the upper limit.

Why don't you try them both on a toy example and see how it goes?

(It's not clear to me whether you want a single joint prior on the precision or a single joint prior — the former seems more likely, but you refer to both `tau.b[k]` and `tau.b` in your example ...)

The manual does say that methods that rely on automatic differentiation won't work with truncation; my guess is that `dconstraint()` would break AD as well.

---

See Section 5.2.7.1, "Truncation" (this is on p. 52, not 53)

> Either of the following forms,

```r
   x ~ dnorm(0, sd = 10) T(0, a)
   x ~ T(dnorm(0, sd = 10), 0, a)
```

> declares that `x` follows a normal distribution between 0 and `a` (inclusive of 0 and `a`). Either boundary
> may be omitted or may be another node, such as `a` in this example. The first form is compatible
> with JAGS, but in NIMBLE it can only be used when reading code from a text file. When writing
> model code in R, the second version must be used.
> Truncation means the possible values of `x` are limited a priori, hence the probability density of `x`
> must be normalized[8]. In this example it would be the normal probability density divided by its
> integral from 0 to `a`. Like JAGS, NIMBLE also provides `I` as a synonym for `T` to accommodate
> older BUGS code, but `T` is preferred because it disambiguates multiple usages of `I` in BUGS.

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker !

At first, I saw on the Nimble Manual page 53 something like this:

"mu1~dnorm(0,1) ; mu2~dnorm(0,1) ; constraint_data~dconstraint(mu1+mu2>0). With constraint_dataset (as data) to 1. This is equivalent to a half-normal distribution on the half-plane 1+2>0"

That is why, I guess the code will be like in my question above.

However, you introduce the idea of Truncated Normal, which is also nice!

Lastly, I'd like to just ask a question to clarify:
So, will a Normal distribution with mean=0 which is truncated from 0, be equal to a Half-Normal distribution?

Comment: Yes ...........